# Saving raster in R using png() and levelplot results in strange lines

Tags: r, png, raster

I think I may have discovered a bug. I'm using levelplot in rasterVis, when I plot the rasters they show up fine in the raster window, however when I try and save them using `png()` the raster has lines through it.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(RColorBrewer)
col<-rasterTheme(region=brewer.pal(8,"YlOrRd"))
r<-raster(ncol=40,nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
b<-"Title"

png(file=paste0(path,"\\",b,".png"), width=1800, height=1800, res=300)
plot<-levelplot(r,main=b,par.settings=col, margin=FALSE, scales=list(draw=FALSE))
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

In the plot window it shows up as it should:
[image]

But saved using `png()`:
[image]

Comment: I have tested your code obtaining a PNG file without white lines.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the `margins` parameter needs to be in the form of a list. Resolves the lines in the images.

`plot<-levelplot(r,main=b,par.settings=col, margin=list(draw=FALSE,scales=list(draw=FALSE)))`

Comment: No. As documented in the help page, `margin` may be a logical or a list. On the other hand, you should not include `scales` inside the `margin` definition.